# Keyboard layout switching unvoluntarily when opening new application

Tags: keyboard-layout

I use three different keyboard layouts, USA, Can and Rus. My default layout is USA.

I have set the keyboard layout to be system-wide instead of application specific because it allows me to keep track of only one status. However, whenever I open a new application, the system-wide layout is always reset to the default layout. For example, if my layout was set to Can and I opened vlc, the layout would then switch back to USA for the whole system. I don't quite understand how or why this could be a desirable behavior...

Do you have any idea as how to get rid of this?

If not, where can I open up a feature request?

EDIT: I did some more testing and in fact, the behavior seems inconsistent. Sometimes the layout will switch, sometimes it won't. I can't pinpoint what is the exact source of the issue.

EDIT2: I think some applications do it, some don't. Ex: VLC does it, gedit doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

[IBus](http://code.google.com/p/ibus/) is intended to allow on-the-fly changes to the input method. Ащк учфьздуб ершы цфы ензувув гыштп <kbd>Ctrl-Space</kbd> to enter Cyrillic; and the same to switch back to my native layout. I also have it configured to accept Pinyin on request, and I'm just learning Chinese so I won't even demonstrate 中文.

Я не говорю на русском так что мой текст вероятно не имеет смысла.